# R - Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) :

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

I am trying to get the userTimeline for multiple users using this

```
j <- lapply(users1[1:2], function(x) userTimeline(x,n=10,includeRts = FALSE))
```

where, users1 is a list of users I have looked up using lookupUsers
However, when I try to run for userTimeline it gives me the following error:

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called 
setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257857/scripting-usertimeline-from-twitter-package-to-data-mine-from-a-list-of-users-in

Comment: @abhiieor Tried the above solution, doesn't work